# Unsupported projection option while getting subdocument in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get a subdocument based on its id but I am getting unsupported projection option.

```
router.get('/:category/:item', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const item = await Category.findOne(
            { category_id: req.params.category },
            { items: { $elementMatch: { item_id: req.params.item } } });

        res.status(200).send(item);    
})

// Schema

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    category_id,
    name,
    items: [
       item_id,
       item_name
    ]
})
```

I hope I have cleared the question, if still confusion, you may ask for clearance.

Comment: [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and not `$elementMatch` The operator name is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time :)